# How to configure access rights for issues in an organization on GitHub?

Tags: github, user-permissions, access-rights, github-organizations

I set up an organization on GitHub and invited some members. Most members have the status `member`. They can create issues, but are not able to set a label or to assign the issue to another member. I figured out, where to set repository permissions: `https://github.com/organizations/{MyOrganization}/settings/member_privileges`. But what I need now are ticket system related permissions.

**How to configure the project ticket system access per user? Additionally: How to do this per team?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not possible yet. Many organisations have used GitHub bots to assign labels automatically, without giving users write access.

Edit: If you are okay with having you're users have write access (i.e. can pull/push/clone), then you can go to `https://github.com/orgs/{org}/teams/{team}/repositories` and configure access there.

[image: GitHub team permissions repos]

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! It it's not possible for users and not possible for teams? What is the sense of teams, if it's not possible to set up access rights for its members?

Comment: It's not possible to set write access on only 'issues'. This might be something GitHub will be introducing, since they've been introducing a lot of new features lately. Right now, you have one of 2 choices: (1) you give all users write access, or you give a team write access (https://www.dropbox.com/s/6b805khvuocr6d5/Screenshot%202016-06-01%2015.26.32.png?dl=0) or (2) you give no write access and have a bot handle ticket changes.

Comment: Note that giving your users/teams write access will allow them to push/clone everything.

Comment: The first variant (to give a team write access) would be OK for now. But does it mean "write access for ALL repositories" or is it possible to define, which repo the team has access to? I didn't find such option.

Comment: Ah, OK, found it: `https://github.com/orgs/{ORGANIZATION}/teams/{TEAM}/repositories` and there under "Repositories" (http://i.stack.imgur.com/vCeEN.png).

Comment: Please complete your answer with the info from the comments, in order I accept it and assign the bounty.

Comment: Done, glad I could help :)

Comment: Yes, you could! :) Thank you very much once again!